# Merging data frames with predictable typos

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, gsub

I need to merge two data frames. The first one looks like this:

```
> df1 <- data.frame(Artist = c("Vincent van ", "Vincent van ", "Theo van Gogh", "Alexandre", "Alexandre"), Location = c("a","a","a","b","c"), time = c(1,2,1,1,1))
> df1
         Artist Location time
1  Vincent van         a    1
2  Vincent van         a    2
3 Theo van Gogh        a    1
4     Alexandre        b    1
5     Alexandre        c    1
```

And the second:

```
> df2 <- data.frame(Artist = c("Vincent van Gogh", "Theo van Gogh", "Alexandre Dumas", "Alexandre Dumas"), HomeNumber = c(123,234,456,789), Location = c( "a","a","b","c"))
> df2
            Artist HomeNumber Location
1 Vincent van Gogh        123        a
2    Theo van Gogh        234        a
3  Alexandre Dumas        456        b
4  Alexandre Dumas        789        c
```

And I want this data frame:

```
> df3 <- data.frame(Artist = c("Vincent van ", "Vincent van ", "Theo van Gogh", "Alexandre", "Alexandre"), Location = c("a","a","a","b","c"), time = c(1,2,1,1,1), HomeNumber = c(123,123,234,456,789))
> df3
         Artist Location time HomeNumber
1  Vincent van         a    1        123
2  Vincent van         a    2        123
3 Theo van Gogh        a    1        234
4     Alexandre        b    1        456
5     Alexandre        c    1        789
>
```

Merging will only work for Theo:

```
    > df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = "Artist", by.y = "Artist", all.x =TRUE)
> df3
         Artist Location.x time HomeNumber Location.y
1     Alexandre          b    1         NA       <NA>
2     Alexandre          c    1         NA       <NA>
3 Theo van Gogh          a    1        234          a
4  Vincent van           a    1         NA       <NA>
5  Vincent van           a    2         NA       <NA>
```

The reason is twofold:
(a) Vincent is missing part of his last name in `df1`.
(b) Alexandre is the name of Alexandre Dumas senior and Alexandre Dumas junior.

I can tackle (a) with `df1$Artist <- gsub("Vincent van $","Vincent van Gogh", df1$Artist)`, but my data is actually very large, and before performing `gsub` I have to first know Vincent's full name. One possible solution would be use `grep("Vincent van "...` in df2, build a function that if the length of the resulting vector is `1` I would use `gsub` to use the returned `df2$Artist` to `df1`. I don't know how to do that.

(b) is a bit tricky for me. One solution I can think of (but cannot code ) is to use an `if`function first to select Alexandre from one location, and then use the solution for (a) to `gsub` the name.

I think solving (a) and (b) would return my desired `df3`. Do you guys have any idea how I can merge these data frames efficiently? Thanks!

EDIT: Note that `Alexandre` is in fact two different units. Thus, when merging the two should have their associated HomeNumber and Location. `Vincent` is one single unit, but with two observations in time.

Comment: You could try with `match()` function, where you can put `location` as argument of match and the rest of columns to show in a new data.frame

Comment: the function `agrep` does fuzzy string matching. You can also take a couple of munging steps like `tolower` and removing punctuation to help...  But the shortest answer is that data munging is tedious!

Comment: @Duck: It might help, but I can't see how it would solve the problem. Thanks! @Justin: I know! Extremely tedious. I've used `tolower`, `chartr`, and some other functions already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hope of that result is sabotaged by the fact that you necessary have two rows in each dataframe that you want to consider as having hte same id, namely the `Alexandre` rows. The JOIN process will make that a 2 x 2 match:

```
df2$short <- substr(df2$Artist, 1,7)
df1$short <- substr(df1$Artist, 1,7)
(dfmer <- merge(df1, df2, by="short") )
#-----
    short      Artist.x Location.x time         Artist.y HomeNumber Location.y
1 Alexand     Alexandre          b    1  Alexandre Dumas        456          b
2 Alexand     Alexandre          b    1  Alexandre Dumas        789          c
3 Alexand     Alexandre          c    1  Alexandre Dumas        456          b
4 Alexand     Alexandre          c    1  Alexandre Dumas        789          c
5 Theo va Theo van Gogh          a    1    Theo van Gogh        234          a
6 Vincent  Vincent van           a    1 Vincent van Gogh        123          a
7 Vincent  Vincent van           a    2 Vincent van Gogh        123          a
```

You can use !duplicated on location and time if you want to pick out the first instances:

```
> dfmer[!duplicated( dfmer[, c("Location.x", "time")]), ]
    short      Artist.x Location.x time         Artist.y HomeNumber Location.y
1 Alexand     Alexandre          b    1  Alexandre Dumas        456          b
3 Alexand     Alexandre          c    1  Alexandre Dumas        456          b
5 Theo va Theo van Gogh          a    1    Theo van Gogh        234          a
7 Vincent  Vincent van           a    2 Vincent van Gogh        123          a
```

In response to the concern (previously not raised that Location needs to be added as a linking variable:

```
> (dfmer <- merge(df1, df2, by=c("short", "Location") ) )
    short Location      Artist.x time         Artist.y HomeNumber
1 Alexand        b     Alexandre    1  Alexandre Dumas        456
2 Alexand        c     Alexandre    1  Alexandre Dumas        789
3 Theo va        a Theo van Gogh    1    Theo van Gogh        234
4 Vincent        a  Vincent van     1 Vincent van Gogh        123
5 Vincent        a  Vincent van     2 Vincent van Gogh        123
```

Comment: Thanks, @Dwin. However, note that `Alexandre` from `Location` 'c' has the wrong HomeNumber

Comment: If HomeNumber is associated with a shared identifier as I believe it is with Location, then you should add the identifier to the `by` variables.